# Regular expression to convert an RGB string to an RGBa string

Tags: java, regex

I am using `String#replace()` to convert an RGB string into an RGBa one. This is the current code:

```
inputString = "rgb(255, 182, 121)";
outputString = inputString.replace( "rgb", "rgba" ).replace( ")", ",255)" ).replace( " ", "" );
```

In the example above, the output will be `"rgba(255,182,121,255)"`. This solution, however, looks a bit convoluted, and I think it could be done more elegantly using a regular expression.

How can I write a regular expression (in Java) to accomplish the same thing as the code above?

Comment: Isn't that working for you? If the strings you need to change are  in the known format, why change anything?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew regular expression gives the more specifc solution thats why I want to try that way

Comment: So, what have you tried then?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried replace method

Comment: `replace` does not allow using regex.

Comment: `replaceAll` takes a regular expression. `replace` does not.

Comment: You should be aware that at the moment the Stack Overflow community [does not approve of "give me a regex that does..." questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/4125191).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278322/regular-expression-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
    inputString.replaceFirst("rgb\\((\\d++),\\s*(\\d++),\\s*(\\d++)\\)", "rgba($1,$2,$3,255)");
```

If you use it more often, better pre-compile the regex with `Pattern.compile()`.